# App crashes when reading excel files

Tags: java, android, file, xls

I'm trying to open xls files. This is my code:

```
File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);
POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
```

And when my app tries to run this line:

```
HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
```

the app crashes.

Where is the problem?

EDIT:

permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace including the type of exception.

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to read that file?

Comment: what perrmision I need?

Comment: Some directories needs root permissions to be read, where is your file?

Comment: It would be better for you to post the crash log so we could see exactly why you are crashing, rather than speculating about what it MIGHT be.

Comment: I haven't LOG, becouse I run app only on devices.